# Data-bind return html a href with data-bind

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, triggers, observable

i have a problem with data-bind into a return observable,

My html code :

```
    <form data-bind="submit: capitalizeNames">

    <p><label>Prénom : <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></label></p>

    <p><label>Nom: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></label></p>

    <p>Nom complet: <strong data-bind="html: fullName" ></strong></p>

    <button type="submit">Valider</button>

</form>
```

My js knwockout :

```
            self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
            var firstName = self.firstName();
            return '<a data-bind="click: $root.test" href="#">' + firstName + '</a>';

        });

        self.test = function() {
            console.log("test");
        }
```

I can't trigger test function

What is solution plz ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The `html` binding does not `applyBindings` to the content it injects. In this particular example I think you're best of using the `text` binding. You can put the `<a>` markup in your HTML instead of your viewmodel.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.firstName = ko.observable("Jane");
  self.lastName = ko.observable("Doe");
  
  self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    var firstName = self.firstName();
    return firstName;
  });

  self.test = function() {
    console.log("test");
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p><label>Prénom : <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></label></p>
<p><label>Nom: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></label></p>
<p>Nom complet: <strong><a data-bind="text: fullName, click: test" href="#"></a></strong></p>
```

If you want to separate your `<a>` markup from the main HTML, it's best to use the [`template` binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) or a [knockout component](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html).